# What happens to Kyle Rittenhouse's AR-15 now?

Tags: evidence, trial, return

It is my understanding, that the rifle was taken away from the accused, and that it was part of the evidence used during trial by the prosecution.

However, now that the trial is over and the man is found not guilty, is he getting it back? By rights he should be, but is that process -- return of all items taken away upon conclusion of the trial -- *automatic*, or does he need to file forms (or even *sue*) to get his property back?

Do these rules vary widely between States (and Federal courts), or is it (almost) the same everywhere?

Comment: @VladimirF, we even [know, where he got the money to buy it](https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2020/nov/25/instagram-posts/kyle-rittenhouse-use-covid-19-stimulus-kenosha/). Can you answer the question, though?

Comment: there are still charges pending against the actual owner (Dominick Black).

Comment: Well, it was bought by his friend in a straw purchase, that is a reason his friend is now prosecuted, but as you wish... If you want to argue that it is still Rittenhouses's gun and not the buyers's gun, there is little point debating that. I deleted my initial objection. It is for the lawyers to determine who is the actual lawful owner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When gun used to kill in self defense and the gun is taken as evidence, can you get it back?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74773/when-gun-used-to-kill-in-self-defense-and-the-gun-is-taken-as-evidence-can-you)

Comment: @RockApe, that question is similar -- indeed, I suspect the asker really had Kyle in mind. But it is vague -- and so the answers are all "it depends"... Depends on the circumstances, that we know about Kyle in particular.